# When viewed on a computer, a youtube video embedded in a hidden div (mobile width) cannot play in full screen. Any ideas how to fix this?

Tags: html, css

This is basically what I have:
HTML

```
<div class="mobile">
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/GL2WM05cxkc" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
@media (min-width: 600px){
  .mobile{display: none;}
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/0sshjqrz/

As you can see in the fiddle, first, the video will not be visible. Follow these steps to reproduce my issue:

1- Resize the browser narrower until the video becomes visible.

2- Play the video, and click fullscreen.

3- The browser will expand and jsFiddle or a whitescreen will cover the video while the sound plays in the background.

Anyone has experience with this issue? I tried removing the css rule and the video works fine.

Screenshot:
[image]
This entire tab with videos has to be hidden on desktop. Therefore I cannot avoid the 'display: none'

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? This line specifically causes the issue: "display: none;"

Comment: I have different videos showing up on desktop. Therefore it's necessary for me to hide the videos on desktop.

Comment: I'm still not sure what you mean. Maybe try adding screenshots of what you are trying to do / show what the GUI issue is?

Comment: Thanks for trying to help! I added a screenshot. Essentially this whole thing is hidden on desktop. Ideally, I would like the fullscreen option to work when the browser width is narrow on a computer (as opposed to an actual phone).